# initialise derived classes from base class

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

I have got a base class similar to this (but the following does not compile):

```
struct Base {
    virtual void foo()=0;

    virtual void init() 
    {
        using Derived = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type;
        *this = Derived(); // does not compile as Base is an abstract class
    }
};
```

`Base` has lots of derived classes and what I want to do is to let all of its derived classes to have this `init()` function inherited from `Base` and initialise themselves (by calling their constructors). And also allow them to override `init()` if they want.

Questions:

1. I know it doesn't compile. What if my Base was not abstract class, does it work? I wonder if the `this` pointer will be interpreted as derived object pointer?
2. How to achieve what I want?

**-------------------------------EDIT--------------------------------------**

To clarify a bit,
The `init()` function is actually doing reset. It reset each derived object to their default state. I want this to be in the Base class with such a default behaviour, and if the derived class want some different reset(), they are free to override it.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good design.  `init` functions introduce a possible failure point.  Why not just use the constructors which will always fire when you create an object?

Comment: @james I agree with @NathanOliver. I don't see a good reason why you need `init` if you automatically get derived-class construction while still allowing for polymorphism through the Base class pointer/reference.

Comment: Can you show a use case? This feels like an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Accomplishing what you *really* want may be easier if you give up this faulty approach.

Comment: Perhaps you should do some research about the [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)?

Comment: So what you're doing, during init, is creating a new object, of the same type, and then calling its default constructor?
But, you already have an instance of that type; so the constructor has already been called.  This isn't init, it's a reset; and it's putting some rather nasty requirements on your derived classes.  Why not just have `virtual void reset() = 0` in your base and let each derived class decide how it should be done.

Comment: @NathanOliver and VermillionAzure, I should probably call it reset() instead of init(), what I want to do is to reset each derived object to their default state. I don't want to copy this code to every derived class, that's why i want them to inherit from Base.

Comment: @UKMonkey, but I want this reset() function to have some default behaviour, which is to reset a derived object to their default state. If the derived class want to have a different reset(), they can override it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am aware of CRTP, but that doesn't help here because I can't assign to *this here as Base is abstract.

Comment: The problem is that `Derived` is equal to `Base`. If you use CRTP then you would have the *actual* child-class.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OK, I think you have answered my question 1. Thanks.

Comment: The type `std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type` is determined at compile-time, like all types. It is `Base`.

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks, this answered my question 1.

Comment: @james you want some default behaviour?  Sure, if it has members then it, Base should reset them.  The Derived then override reset, reset their own members and call the base class function;  or even have a protected `virtual void resetImpl() = 0` in the base, which is then called in the reset so that all the derived classses must say how to reset their memebers and the base will always be done.

Comment: @UKMonkey as I explained above, the default behaviour for the reset() function, if not overridden, is to reset the derived to their initial state. So if a derived class has not overridden reset(), it should still be able to do reset. There are lots of derived class here, I can't & don't want to implement reset() for each of them. That's why I want Base to do this.

Comment: Base-From-Member idiom could be relevant http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/utility/doc/html/base_from_member.html

Comment: If you want to reset 100 derived classes, you will need to write 100 reset functions. You can organise them differently: as member functions in their respective classes, as standalone functions, or as instantiations of the same function template, but you will need to have 100 separate declarations/definitions/statements/somethings, one per derived class. There's no way around it.

Answer (score 1):

A few users mentioned CRTP (Curiously Recurring Template Pattern) in the comments, without showing a concrete solution, so here is one:

```
template <typename CRTP>
struct Base {
  virtual void foo()=0;

  virtual void init() 
  {
    static_cast<CRTP&>(*this) = CRTP{};
  }
};

struct Derived : public Base<Derived> {
  void foo() override {}
};
```

Comment: As I explained in the comments, I am aware of CRTP. This approach requires not only the modification of the Base class, but also EACH derived class, which is impossible in my case.

Comment: @james is adding `<Derived>` next to `public Base` to each derived class already too much in your case?

Comment: Yes, that's already too much for my case - there are lots of classes derived from Base. By 'too much', I mean not only the work to modify each derived class, but also to get permission to do so.

Comment: @james ok. I guess it is mission impossible in C++ then: if you want to create a clean instance of your Derived class, how can Base know how much space to allocate for it, etc., without access to the definition of the derived class? Constructors cannot be virtual...

Answer (score 0):

You want to call a different function based on the type of the derived class. This is polymorphism in C++. You have at your disposal the usual suspects:

1. Have a virtual function which derived classes override. i.e. dispatch based on dynamic type.
2. Find the static type in some way and use overloading. i.e. dispatch based on static type.

CRTP is one way to accomplish the second, having the derived say its true type at the point of inheritance.

An extremely *hacky* way to accomplish the second, which to be clear I'm **not** recommending, but may be required in a dysfunctional organization in which you have no other options: attempt to dynamic_cast to the various options for the derived class. This is likely to be fragile. But even having a reset function at all, instead of using construction and destruction is fragile.

I recommend re-evaluating your need for a reset member function, ask on SO about what you are trying to accomplish with it, and try not to lower the quality of your work product as an end-run around interacting with your organization. (My opinion.)